# Is there a way to configure a Word 2016 install to prevent proofing exceptions

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I can find plenty of instructions on how to hide spelling errors within a specific document (Word Options->Proofing->Hide spelling errors in this document only).  But I need to configure word to ignore document exceptions and force it to highlight all spelling errors regardless of the exception setting.  I have a workgroup where some of the members hide spelling errors by default, whenever they edit a document it flags the document so spelling highlighting is disabled for all other people in the workgroup who open it.  I don't want to tell the user to stop hiding spelling errors, and I do not control their computer, so any solutions would have to be on our end.

Is there a way to configure a Word 2016 install to prevent proofing exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

When you review documents, run `Recheck Document`.

> [Check spelling and grammar in Office 2010 and later - Office
>   Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-spelling-and-grammar-in-Office-2010-and-later-5cdeced7-d81d-47de-9096-efd0ee909227)
>
> Recheck spelling and grammar that you previously ignored
>
> In Word ..., you can force a recheck of the words and grammar
>   that you previously skipped by doing the following:
>
> 1. Open the document or item that you want to check.
> 2. On the **File** menu, click **Options**, and then:
>
>    - In Word: Click **Proofing**, and then under **When correcting spelling and grammar in Word**, click **Recheck Document**.
>    - ...
> 3. Click **Yes** when you see the warning message about resetting the spelling and grammar checker.
> 4. Click **OK** in the dialog box to get back to the document, and then run the spelling and grammar checker again.